# Cómo puedo agregar un atributo en la transacción de usuarios de GAM (Genexus)

Tags: genexus

Estoy probando GAM en Genexus, estoy utilizando el Pattern WorkWithPlus.

Adicionalmente he creado en mi KB una transacción FACULTAD:

[image: Transacción Facultad]

¿Es posible añadir **FacultadId** y **EscuelaId** como atributos del **Usuario** que se genera con GAM? (Es decir, que se muestre así y se almacene en los datos del usuario que se está ingresando):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes extender las entidades del GAM. Fíjate este link en la wiki de GeneXus: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?19634,Extensibility+of+GAM+entity+properties Es bastante sencillo de utilizar. El tema es que la integridad referencial la debes mantener tu.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/213636)

Comment: Gracias! He logrado insertar y eliminar un usuario con el atributo, pero tengo un problema en la visualización y en la edición, debido a que no me carga el dato que se encuentra almacenado, y no se cómo traerlo al combobox

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que utilizar los atributos dinámicos del User de GAM.
Te paso la [doc](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?19634,Extensibility%20of%20GAM%20entity%20properties) oficial de esos atributos.

En tu caso, asumiendo que estas cargando una variable &GAMUser para crear el usuario, esto seria lo que tenes que hacer para agregar el atributo extendido FacultadId.

```
&GAMUserAttribute       = new() //&GAMUserAttribute es una variable de tipo GAMUserAttribute
&GAMUserAttribute.Id    = "FacultadId" 
&GAMUserAttribute.Value = &FacultadId 
&GAMUser.Attributes.Add(&GAMUserAttribute)
&GAMUser.Save()
commit
```

Comment: Gracias! He logrado insertar y eliminar un usuario con el atributo, pero tengo un problema en la visualización y en la edición, debido a que no me carga el dato que se encuentra almacenado, y no se cómo traerlo al combobox

Comment: Haciendo algo de este estilo deberías poder recorrer todos los atributos dinámicos que hayas agregado al usuario.

&GAMUser.Load(&UserGUIDselected) 
For &UserAttr In &GAMUser.Attributes 
    &UserAttribute = &UserAttr.Id
    &AttrValue = &UserAttr.Value
EndFor

Otra opci{on es utilizar los metodos: GetAttribute y SetAttribute (este sirve tanto para insertar un nuevo atributo dinámico como para hacer un update de uno existente)

&GAMUser.Load(&UserGUIDselected) 
&GAMUserAttribute = &GAMUser.GetAttribute(&AttributeId,&Errors)